# How to return result sets from Stored Procedure?

Tags: java, stored-procedures, jdbc, derby

I created a Stored Procedure where I can fetch all my data that I inserted in my following textfields. How can I fetch all of this data by calling my Callable Statement? I think this is the easiest way than Batch Statement based on what I read. I only drag and drop this following components just a practice purposes.

**Stored Procedure**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE show_data(OUT FULLNAME VARCHAR(50), OUT ADDRESS VARCHAR(50))
PARAMETER STYLE JAVA
LANGUAGE JAVA
READS SQL DATA
DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1
EXTERNAL NAME 'Frame.searchButton'
```

I used OUT parameter to retrieve values using getXXX() methods. I'm just little bit confuse since this is my first time to use Stored Procedure in derby.

**GUI**

[image]

After the user search the following record in Database. If the value exist it will print to the designated textfields.

**SOURCE CODE**

```
    String searchRecord = searchTf.getText();

    String searchQuery = "SELECT * FROM SAMPLEONLY";
    ResultSet data[] = null;//Why should I use this array?

    try (Connection myConn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
        PreparedStatement myPs = myConn.prepareStatement(searchQuery);)
        {
            String addFullname = fullnameTf.getText();//first field
            String addAddress = addressTf.getText();//second field

            data[0] = myPs.executeQuery();

            CallableStatement cs = myConn.prepareCall("{ call showData(?, ?)}");

            cs.setString(1, addFullname);
            cs.setString(2, addAddress);

            boolean hasResults = cs.execute();
            if (hasResults) {
            ResultSet rs = cs.getResultSet();
            while (rs.next()) {
                String getFullname = rs.getString(1);//get the value
                String getAddress = rs.getString(2);

                fullnameTf.setText(getFullname);//set the text here
                addressTf.setText(getAddress);  
            }//end of while
            rs.close();//close the resultset
        }//end of if
    }//end of try
        catch (SQLException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }//end of else
}
```

After I insert in Search textfields it throws me a error NullPointerExeption. I follow Derby Reference Manual so I can have a guide writing a proper Stored Procedure. This code is mine most of the part. Guide me if I missed something wrong. Feel free to comment thanks.

Comment: `data` is `null` when `data[0]` is used.

Comment: How can I retrieve my data from database? Thanks